# How to delete an array of imageUrl all at once flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a snapshot of an array that contains imageUrl here. But I want to delete it all at once when I press the button. How can I do that is it possible?

```
             StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('widgets')
                      .doc(widgets)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                   //Array of snapshot imageUrl
                    var imageUrl = snapshot.data?['imageUrl'];
                    if (snapshot.data == null) {
                      return Container();
                    }
                    return body: ...
                     ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => {openDialog(imageUrl)},

                    //Dialog to delete the imageUrl
Future openDialog1(imageUrl) => showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Center(child: Text('Delete image')),
        content: const Text(
            'Warning.\n Once you delete this. You can not bring this back.'),
        actions: [
          OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () async => {
              await storage.ref('images/$imageUrl').delete(),
            },
            child: const Text(
              'Confirm',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ));
```

images:

**ImageUrl in my Firebase Firestore**
[image]

**Image that I want to delete in the FB storage**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To delete a file, first create [a reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/create-reference) to that file. Then call the `delete()` method on that reference.

```
// Create a reference to the file to delete
final desertRef = storageRef.child("images/desert.jpg");

// Delete the file
await desertRef.delete();
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/delete-files#delete_a_file